# Последовательное добавление классов

Tags: javascript, dom, javascript-events, setinterval

```
const $cells = document.getElementsByClassName('cell'); // тут блоки которым добавляются классы 
const $startButton = document.getElementById('start');  // кнопка активации
$startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  for (let elem of $cells) {
    elem.classList.add('cell__anim');
  }
});
```

Задумка в том, что при нажатии на кнопку, нужно добавить класс `cell__anim` всем блокам `$cells` последовательно, т.е. друг за другом, через определенный промежуток времени.
Пытался пропихнуть `setInterval` внутрь функции, но все классы все равно добавлялись одновременно.

P.S.: чистый JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Через Promise не нужно, хоть и можно :)
Почему считаю что в данном случае промис не нужен - потому что обертка в объект обещания тут не выполняет какой-либо полезной работы... То есть, обертка в промис особо сильно не вредит в любом случае, но эта конкретная задача вполне успешно решается и без такой обертки:

```js
generateElements();

const $cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
const $startButton = document.getElementById('start');
$startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  $cells.forEach((cell, idx) => setTimeout(() => {
    cell.classList.add('cell__anim');
  }, 100 * idx));
}, { once: true });


function generateElements() {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
    `<section>
      ${Array.from({ length: 50 }, (_, i) => `<div class="cell">${i + 1}</div>`).join('')}
    </section>`
  );
}
```

```css
section { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; margin: 1rem 0 0; padding: 1px; }
.cell { flex: 0 0 1.2em; line-height: 1.2; margin: -1px 0 0 -1px; padding: 0.5em; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #ccc; transition: background-color 0.3s ease; }
.cell.cell__anim { background-color: #ded; }
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

Тут просто устанавливается отдельный таймаут для каждого элемента, с последовательным увеличением значения задержки.

---

А вот и одним `setInterval`'ом:

```js
generateElements();

const $cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
const $startButton = document.getElementById('start');
$startButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  let curIdx = -1;
  const interval = setInterval(() => {
    const cell = $cells[++curIdx];
    if (!cell) return void(clearInterval(interval));
    cell.classList.add('cell__anim');
  }, 100);
}, { once: true });


function generateElements() {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
    `<section>
      ${Array.from({ length: 50 }, (_, i) => `<div class="cell">${i + 1}</div>`).join('')}
    </section>`
  );
}
```

```css
section { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; margin: 1rem 0 0; padding: 1px; }
.cell { flex: 0 0 1.2em; line-height: 1.2; margin: -1px 0 0 -1px; padding: 0.5em; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #ccc; transition: background-color 0.3s ease; }
.cell.cell__anim { background-color: #ded; }
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

На каждой итерации последовательно увеличиваем индекс элемента в коллекции (пока не выйдем за ее границы) и добавляем класс элементу по текущему индексу.

---

В обоих случаях используется метод `querySelectorAll`, который возвращает коллекцию элементов в порядке их следования в документе.

Использование опции `once` метода `addEventListener` просто для упрощения - так слушатель будет автоматически удален после первого события (т.е., с этой опцией не нужно самостоятельно удалять слушатель или использовать переменную-флажок "уже запущено").

---

---

Бонусное решение - вариант применения промисов, который считаю единственно оправданным в данном случае:

```js
generateElements();

const $cells = document.querySelectorAll('.cell');
const $startButton = document.getElementById('start');
const sleep = delay => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, delay));
$startButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
  for (const cell of $cells) {
    cell.classList.add('cell__anim');
    await sleep(100);
  }
}, { once: true });


function generateElements() {
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',
    `<section>
      ${Array.from({ length: 50 }, (_, i) => `<div class="cell">${i + 1}</div>`).join('')}
    </section>`
  );
}
```

```css
section { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; margin: 1rem 0 0; padding: 1px; }
.cell { flex: 0 0 1.2em; line-height: 1.2; margin: -1px 0 0 -1px; padding: 0.5em; text-align: center; border: 1px solid #ccc; transition: background-color 0.3s ease; }
.cell.cell__anim { background-color: #ded; }
```

```html
<button id="start">Start</button>
```

Плюс в значительном улучшении читаемости кода, а минус в создании лишних объектов. Оправдано ли это - вопрос личных предпочтений и решаемых задач... я использую "опциональную" промисификацию только когда **одновременно** выполняются три условия:

1. если присутствуют подзадачи где накладные расходы на нее несущественны (с малым кол-вом итераций);
2. если обертка в промис является достаточно общей, generic (когда проект большой и можно переиспользовать промисифицированный код в нескольких подзадачах, не изменяя его);
3. когда это оправдано реальной практической пользой (не для красоты и не для "тимлид, посмотри, я умею в промисы", а для пользы дела).

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: А почему ты написал: "Через Promise **не нужно**, хоть и можно", у них какой то косяк есть? или почему?

Comment: @yar85 хороший, полезный ответ. Отдельная благодарность за ценные пояснения.

Comment: @Nick, косяка у промисов нет - просто здесь нет потребности в их использовании, что примеры и демонстрируют. Промисы в целом бывают нужны, их применение бывает оправдано: как и любой инструмент, они имеют свою область применения. Но именно тут, в данной задаче, промис по сути лишь создает дополнительную объектную обертку (имхо не имеющую практического смысла). Сравни первый пример этого ответа с решением на промисе... код очень похож, и довольно очевидно что ожидание промиса не выполняет никакой полезной работы: ведь надо выполнить выражение после таймаута, и только.

Comment: @Nick, некоторый смысл появился бы при другом использовании промиса: если добавление класса разместить в синхронном коде, то можно использовать фабрику/генератор промисов как аналог `sleep` в других языках. Только опять же, это (имхо) совершенно ненужное усложнение простой операции: считаю что чем проще и быстрее реализовано успешное решение задачи - тем лучше (потому что простые и эффективные решения легче воспринимать, развивать, и поддерживать). Да, аналог `sleep` повысит читаемость, но увы, негативно скажется на эффективности (лишние объекты). Стоит ли оно того - очень неоднозначный вопрос

Comment: @Nick, добавил в ответ пример с хелпером `sleep`, чтобы иллюстрировать то о чем написано выше. Сам предпочел бы (и советую) второй вариант, на `setInterval` - считаю его наиболее разумным решением в данном случае: успешно решает задачу минимальным усилием; понятная/очевидная логика без магии; применимо к большим выборкам; легко поддерживается (например, замена на `requestAnimationFrame` это дело пары минут).

Comment: @yar85 круто, спасибо за очень развернутый ответ и время.

Answer (score 3):

Через Promise нужно

```js
const $cells = document.getElementsByClassName('cell') // тут блоки которым добавляются классы 
const $startButton = document.getElementById('start') // кнопка активации
$startButton.addEventListener('click', async()=> { /// async
        for (let elem of $cells){
            await new Promise(resolve=>{ /// ждём исполнения функции resolve
                setTimeout(()=>{
                    elem.classList.add('cell__anim')
                    resolve()
                },300) /// Промежуток
                
            })
            
        }
})
```

```css
.cell__anim{
                color: red;
            }
```

```html
<ul>
            <li class="cell">TEST</li>
            <li class="cell">TEST</li>
            <li class="cell">TEST</li>
            <li class="cell">TEST</li>
            <li class="cell">TEST</li>
            <li class="cell">TEST</li>
            <li class="cell">TEST</li>
            <li class="cell">TEST</li>
        </ul>
        <button id="start">START</button>
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, в `Promise` вообще 0 был,  сижу разбираюсь. Прикольная вроде штука)

Comment: @Nick , согласен. Promise очень интересный. В отличие от обычного setTimeout(foo,ind*100) , через Promise можно делать динамичное кол-во секунд между промежутками , а не статичное как в способе выше